# Article usage in 'the widow is sister to your own noble wife', 'the Lady Lysa' phrases

Tags: grammar, articles

I'm reading "A Game of Thrones", and I've encountered the following sentence in a dialogue between the Grand Maester and Eddard Stark:

> I recall now, the widow is sister to your own noble wife.

Why 'sister' is used with no article? Shouldn't it be 'a sister' or 'the sister'? If it is a mistake, why the Grand Master made it?

In other sentences I also see that he tells either "the Lady Lysa" or "Lady Lysa":

> ..., and the Lady Lysa was never that
>
> Lady Lysa would not permit the boy to enter the sickroom

Are they both correct?

Comment: It is supposed to look like archaic usage. Asking movie scripts to be always grammatical according to current usage is a lost cause. Using 'recall' in place of _remember_, and 'to your own noble wife' should be a clue.

Comment: That usage survives in British English, e.g. she is mother to two fine boys, I am brother to a fool,  'the child is father to the man'.

Comment: ,,, Yes; this is probably Master's _null article_, as in Cowper's 'I am monarch of all I survey'. Even more definite than the definite article.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Perhaps the Q is worth a chew. Gonna write it up?

Comment: @Rattler The basics have been covered on ELU already, and from what I remember of Master's article, he didn't cover many actual examples of the null article, and I'd say some fixed expressions come outside his analysis (eg _break camp_, _cry wolf_, _play possum_) with there being no hint at all of any article. In 'I am Ø2 monarch of all I survey', adding 'the' is not unreasonable, so this is the null article. Contrast 'We're having Ø1 curry tonight' where 'a' would fit in and the zero article (coded Ø1) is present. // Here, 'is sister/mother to' is perhaps more likely to be a fixed expression.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Yes, of course the treatment of the _null article_ has been discussed at length on this site...what I was referring to was the use in this kind of case. Until this moment, I was unaware of the article from Masters that you cited, and the example  of "'I am monarch of all I survey" from Cowper was interesting, but wasn't he being humorous? I still think that at its core, there is possibly an interesting question here  which has not been dealt with adequately on this site. I may be wrong.

Comment: My boss at Bristol City Council in the 1970s used to say "I am Finance Officer" to people on the phone.